# How can I change this code to upload multiple files in django and python?

Tags: python, django

My English is not good.. Hope you understand that..

I(beginner) use django and python, and I try to upload multiple files.

finally i find working code but It is difficult to apply to the original code

What am I doing wrong?
(`form.py`, `model.py` is same each other)

1. working ex code(`views.py`)

```
def a(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist("files")
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                file_instance = Upload(file_upload=f)
                file_instance.save()
            return render(request, 'single_pages/about_me.html', {'form':form,})
            # return HttpResponse(" File uploaded! ")
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'single_pages/about_me.html', {'form': form})
```

2. my Spaghetti code(`views.py`)

```
def a(request, pk):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            files = request.FILES.getlist('files')
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                comment.post = post
                comment.author = request.user
                comment.save()
                for f in files:
                    file_instance = Comment(file_upload=f)
                    file_instance.save()

                return redirect(comment.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            return redirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = {'content', 'file_upload', 'head_image'}
        files = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()

    head_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/images/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='blog/files/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author}::{self.content}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'{self.post.get_absolute_url()}#comment-{self.pk}'

    def get_file_name(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file_upload.name)

    def get_file_ext(self):
        return self.get_file_name().split('.')[-1]
```

What should I do..
thank you very much